# Debian install woes

Tags: debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[hide preview]
Issues start with the first points on the installation file (comments will be listed with the appropriate numbers)

1.1 Configure your Ubuntu repositories Sorry - - I had used a hard-link to a 'Debian' instruction set so I wouldn't be configuring my ubuntu repositories rather my debian ones. 1.2 Setup your computer to accept software from packages.ros.org. ROS Kinetic ONLY supports Wily (Ubuntu 15.10), Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) and Jessie (Debian 8) for debian packages.

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

commands given (please note that Debian 8 (Jessie) is explicitly mentioned as being supported) don't give any kind of result like what might be wanted. - - vis there is no directory in sources.list.d called ros-latest.list and the command hangs there and doesn't 'do' anything to a somewhat noob the phrase '$(lsb_release -sc) main' doesn't mean much - - - it took me a while to understand that I needed to have 'xenial' here (a space after .../ubuntu) followed by a space and then the word 'main'. 1.3Set up your key

apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0xB01FA116

gets

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.6yfkBfPICO --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0XB01FA116 gpg: "0XB01FA116" not a key ID: skipping

which somehow doesn't seem to be a useful result

did the apt-get update - - just in case something useful might be there and then

next the command aptitude install ros-kinetic-desktop-full was used with the result (aptitude deals with dependencies better therefore its use)

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/6a526ee79ac53f0f0e404cbc3e33f13d

With my only real option being a non-install.

All this is being run on a vm set up as debian stable (jessie 8.5) trying to install kinetic. I hope that I have been able to provide enough information enough information vis a vi the warnings and errors so that someone might be able to point me to the instruction set for Debian jessie so that I might be able to install ros which I would love to examine in some detail.

TIA

Dee

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242530/debian-install-woes/) by [dabeegmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27847/dabeegmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you've interpreted the instructions incorrectly in two places:

In 1.2, you set the release name to `xenial`; which is the name of the ubuntu release. Ubuntu uses different package version from the Debian releases, and this is likely what is causing your dependency challenges later. The command as listed should work, but if you've mis-typed it in some way it could be waiting for additional input. If `lsb_release -sc` isn't retrieving your OS name for some reason, use `jessie`, since that is the proper short name for your Debian release:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Note that the type and placement of quotes and other punctuation is **VERY IMPORTANT**. The command-line uses them to figure out which parts are commands, which parts are arguments, and how to interpret your command. If you miss a quote it my assume that you wanted to enter a newline as part of the command, and will happily accept more input until it gets the matching quote.

In 1.3, the error message indicates that you've mis-typed the key ID: it should be `0xB01FA116`. Note the lowercase `x`. Again, it is important to enter the commands **EXACTLY** as per the instructions.

If you're having trouble, I recommend that you copy and paste the commands into your terminal, instead of trying to re-type them. There's much less opportunity for error that way.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1